# Kendo grid noRecord template unexpected behavior with footer template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented kendo grid in my project. To show the footer values, I have added footer template to my grids. I have also added no record template to display message to user when data is not present. It is working as expected but when this functionality is implemented for hierarchy grid then it shows weird behavior.

It shows the "No record" template below footer while it should display between header and footer. Here is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                            },
                            pageSize: 6,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 600,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        dataBound: function() {
                            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "FirstName",
                                title: "First Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "LastName",
                                title: "Last Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Country",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "City",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Title"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

                function detailInit(e) {
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                          //  data: [{
                            //  OrderID: 1,
                             // ShipCountry: 'First Country',
                            //  ShipName: 'Ship Name',
                            //  ShipAddress: 'SHip Address'
                            //}],
                          data: [],
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                      noRecords: {
    template: "No data available on current page."
  },

                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "OrderID", width: "110px", footerTemplate: 'This is footer.' },
                            { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                            { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "300px" }
                        ]
                    });
                }


            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Below sample has static footer while in my application I am binding aggregate functions. Here is the [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IfuFo/2) for the implementation. Am I doing something wrong or this is kendo API related issue?

Comment: This is very wierd tho. You should post it on their forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `scrollable: true` in the detail grid will cause the `noRecords` template to be rendered above the columns `footerTemplate`

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how it works but it resolved the issue. :)